# Why can't cURL and wget connect to footpatrol.com

Tags: wget, curl

Every time I try to use either wget or cURL to connect it keeps on saying `failed: Resource temporarily unavailable.` for wget and `curl: (7) Failed to connect to footpatrol.com port 443: Timed out` for cURL. This is in spite the fact that I can visit footpatrol.com on my web browser and it loads perfectly fine. What can I do to access footpatrol.com via my terminal?

Comment: What's the actual full command line you are running?

Comment: @djsmiley2k wget https://footpatrol.com and curl -v https://footpatrol.com

Answer (score 3):

This is one weird website.

At first I used Firefox, and found that the website
can only be accessed via http://www.footpatrol.com/, not via `https`,
which then redirects to https://www.footpatrol.com/, and then the
website works.

However, it then sets up cookies which block any future access via `https`
or `http`. You have to delete these cookies to again access to it once,
and once only, via http://www.footpatrol.com/.

In all other cases I got the error of "Access Denied".

Then I used Chrome, and had no difficulties whatsoever to access
https://www.footpatrol.com/.

My conclusion is that this website has very strange restrictions on access,
and returns strange error codes whenever these restrictions are violated.
Evidently `wget` is not acceptable either.

Try Chrome, and if it works for you, you may try to duplicate the entire
request by Chrome, including all HTTP headers, to maybe make this work.